# Kettle: custom error row in dialog

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm designing a custom plugin for Pentaho PDI (AKA Kettle).
In case of error, my `processRow()` method sends an error row through `putError()` with a specific meta layout. 
The run-time behavior is fine, but when connecting steps at design time, the dialogs complain because they believe that the error row has a different layout.

My question is: how can I set the `RowMetaInterface` for the error row used by the dialog ? I've tried by invoking the `BaseStep.getErrorRowMeta()` and  `BaseStep.setErrorRowMeta()` methods, but the dialog still sees the wrong layout.